# postgresql: grouping with json columns, eliminating nulls

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a postgres query that returns a result set simplified as follows, with an id column and two json columns.

```
my_id     |  col_a       |  col_b
(integer) |  (json)      |  (json)
----------------------------------------
 5001        ["a", "b"]     <NULL>
 5001        <NULL>         ["c", "d"]
```

My question is: what is the best way in postgres to aggregate this result? e.g.:

```
my_id     |  col_a       |  col_b
(integer) |  (json)      |  (json)
----------------------------------------
 5001        ["a", "b"]     ["c", "d"]
```

Comment: please, add your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I don't know your actual query, you can JOIN rows where col_a is not null with rows where col_b is not null.

> ```
> create table test(my_id int, col_a json, col_b json);
> insert into test values
> (5001, '["a", "b"]', null),
> (5001, null, '["c", "d"]');
> ```

> ```
>     select t1.my_id, t1.col_a, t2.col_b 
>     from test t1
>     inner join (select my_id, col_b
>                 from test
>                 where col_b is not null) t2
>     on t1.my_id = t2.my_id
>     where t1.col_a is not null;
> ```
>
> ```
> my_id | col_a      | col_b     
> ----: | :--------- | :---------
>  5001 | ["a", "b"] | ["c", "d"]
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1db34ade319e38cd5718ac392846530a)*